# Orionjs collection : Expected object, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, meteor-orion

I'm experiencing little trouble getting [Orionjs](http://www.orionjs.org/) working within Angular-Meteor especially with the collections.
I had my old mongodb declarations, for instance : 
`Gallery = new Mongo.Collection('gallery')` and so one.

As the [documentation told](http://docs.orionjs.org/) , I wrote 
`Gallery = new orion.collection('gallery')` but what I get is

```
Error: Match error: Expected object, got undefined
    at exports.check (packages/check/match.js:34:1)
    at new orion.collection (packages/orionjs:collections/new.js:8:3)
    at meteorInstall.shared.collections.js (shared/collections.js:1:11)
```

So I tried to start a project from scratch with this framework.
Fact is, it doesn't work neither with Iron Router nor Flow Router.

Can anyone hit me with any hint about it?
Thank you guys.

Comment: Haven't used Orionjs before, but I think it's referring to the 2nd argument of orion.collection, you have to pass in an object with some options (see http://docs.orionjs.org/v1.7/collections).

Comment: Oh!
I tried to add the argument but fact is, I had to create a schema.
Thank you so much for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally OrionJS expect a schema detail like the label for singular and plural names, navigation detail, table layout for displaying data and so on.Here's a typical company collection shown below:

```
Company = new orion.collection('company', {
  singularName: orion.helpers.getTranslation('company.singularName'), 
  pluralName: orion.helpers.getTranslation('company.pluralName'), 
  title: orion.helpers.getTranslation('company.title'),
  link: {
    title: orion.helpers.getTranslation('company.title'),
    parent: 'collections-abc'
  }, 

  tabular: {
    columns: [
      { data: '_id', title: orion.helpers.getTranslation('company.schema.id') },
      { data: 'name', title: orion.helpers.getTranslation('company.schema.name') }
    ]
  }
});
```

You can also pass a null JSON if you do not wish to show page directly. Usually it expects a JSON like the one shown above.